# Вывод по одному из определенных url своего css

Tags: php

```
$page = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
echo $page['path'];
```

Всегда выдает index.php на всех страницах. А мне нужно по одному из определенных url'ов вывести свой css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Элемент $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']**

В элемент $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] помещается имя скрипта, начиная от корневой директории виртуального хоста, т.е. если строка запроса представляет собой адрес

```
http://www.mysite.ru/test/index.php?id=1&test=wet&id_theme=512
```

то элемент $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] будет содержать фрагмент "/test/index.php". Как правило, этот же фрагмент помещается в элемент $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].

**Полный адрес к скрипту**

```
<?php 
  echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Кстати ЧПУ тоже получается ссылается на индекс (у меня так). Огромное спасибо за разъяснения.